# Contar el número total de archivos en subcarpetas contenidas en varias carpetas con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy empezando a programar en Python, pero aún soy muy novato. Tengo un directorio (Dataset) con la siguiente estructura de carpetas y subcarpetas:

- fold_0:

  - A

    - Class_1

      - files...
    - Class_2

      - files...
  - B

    - Class_1

      - files...
    - Class_2

      - files...
  - C

    - Class_1

      - files...
    - Class_2

      - files...
- fold_1

  - A

    - Class_1

      - files...
    - Class_2

      - files...
  - B

    - Class_1

      - files...
    - Class_2

      - files...
  - C

    - Class_1

      - files...
    - Class_2

      - files...
- ...
- ...
- fold_10

Tengo que contar el número de archivos para cada clase (subcarpetas Class_1 y Class_2), distinguiendo por subcarpetas A, B y C, y distinguiendo por carpetas desde fold_0 hasta fold_10.

La salida que espero sería (los números son solo como ejemplo):

- fold_0:
- A: 8

  - Class_1: 5
  - Class_2: 3
- B: 5

  - Class_1: 2
  - Class_2: 3
- C: 10

  - Class_1: 4
  - Class_2: 6
- fold_1:
- A: 6

  - Class_1: 3
  - Class_2: 3
- B: 7

  - Class_1: 2
  - Class_2: 5
- C: 11

  - Class_1: 5
  - Class_2: 6
- ...
- ...

Y así para cada carpeta desde fold_0 hasta fold_10. Finalmente, tengo que sumar todas las cantidades agrupando todas las carpetas desde fold_0 hasta fold_10. El resultado sería:

- Total A: A(de fold_0) + A(de fold_1) + ... + A(de fold_10) = 8 + 6 + ...
- Total B: B(de fold_0) + B(de fold_1) + ... + B(de fold_10) = 5 + 7 + ...
- Total C: C(de fold_0) + C(de fold_1) + ... + C(de fold_10) = 10 + 11 + ...
- Total Class_1: total Class_1(de fold_0) + total Class_1(de fold_1) + ... + total Class_1(de fold_10) = (5 + 2 + 4) + (3 + 2 + 5) +  ...
- Total Class_2: total Class_2(de fold_0) + total Class_2(de fold_1) + ... + total Class_2(de fold_10) = (3 + 3 + 6) + (3 + 5 + 6) + ...

Con el siguiente código puedo contar los archivos, pero no es la salida que espero:

```
import os
path = 'Dataset'
for dir,subdir,files in os.walk(path):
    print(dir,' ', str(len(files)))
```

La salida que obtengo es:

```
Dataset/Fold0   0
Dataset/Fold0/A    0
Dataset/Fold0/A/Class_1   83
Dataset/Fold0/A/Class_2   93
Dataset/Fold0/B   0
Dataset/Fold0/B/Class_1   71
Dataset/Fold0/B/Class_2   84
Dataset/Fold0/C   0
Dataset/Fold0/C/Class_1   626
Dataset/Fold0/C/Class_2   755
...
...
```

¿Podría alguien ayudarme?

Comment: Te recomiendo agregar la etiqueta Python para que tu pregunta llegue a màs gente.

Comment: Puedes guardar el resultado de len(files) en un diccionario cuya clave sea el directorio y el valor la cantidad de archivos que tiene. Luego accedes a las claves correspondientes y haces las cuentas que necesitas. Te sirve la idea???

Comment: Un problema que veo es, ¿Quién o qué asegura la integridad de la información? Es decir, ¿Cómo puedes saber que no hay archivos `Class_2` dentro de las carpetas `Class_1`? Construyendo sobre el comentario de Dante, yo creo que un diccionario sería la mejor opción, pero la integridad de la información debe asegurarse previamente o tu código debería considerar que es posible que los archivos no estén en la carpeta correcta

Comment: Gracias a @DanteS. Creando un diccionario ya me sirve. La integridad de los datos está asegurada. Tengo un dataset de imágenes con las subcarpetas ordenadas correctamente.

Comment: Perfecto, puedes cerrar la pregunta ya que no hubo necesidad de redactar una respuesta completa y se resolvió con los comentarios. De esa forma ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Saludos.

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia @HeytalePazguato, ¿cómo cierro la pregunta?

Comment: @espartian, en la parte inferior de tu pregunta aparecen algunas opciones, entre ellas están "Compartir", "Editar", etc... Saludos!